# OpenEdge Progress DB Export

Tags: sql, linux, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I have an OpenEdge Progress v10.1C linux server with a bunch of data on it. We're migrating this data to an SQL server. I just need to get the data off of the server somehow, be it a bunch of CSVs of tables or an sql file or whatever - I just need the raw data.

I have no experience with this server and I can't seem to figure out how to even connect to it or anything. I just know where the data directory is and that I have a bunch of files in /usr/dlc/bin which are for management (like _progres, pro, ...)

I would really appreciate any help extracting this data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a command line execute $DLC/bin/showcfg -- this will reveal what you have available for licenses which will have an impact on what options you have to export the data.

If your license allows, to get simple text files you can use the "data dictionary dump".  To run that start a session from a command line like this:

mpro dbName -p dict.p

If your licenses are good that will bring up the data dictionary.  Navigate to Admin -> Dump Data and Definitions -> Table Contents  if you get that far then go ahead and dump what you need.

If the database is large this may take a while.  Maybe even a long while.

If you cannot navigate to that point then then you do not have an appropriate license.  In that case if you have SQL installed and configured then the simplest thing may be to just extract the data with that.  But since you are asking this question that seems unlikely -- none the less... type "ps -ef | grep sql" and see if anything shows up.  If it does you should be able to connect an ODBC client.

If all else fails you can try to get someone to write you a custom extract program.  That will need to be done by someone with a compiler license and they will need to provide you with r-code.  That sort of thing is usually provided as a commercial service.